# How to see keras.engine.sequential.Sequential

Tags: keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am new to Keras and deep learning and was working with MNIST on Keras. When I created a model using

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(512,activation = 'relu',input_shape=(28*28,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(32,activation ='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
```

and then I printed it

```
print(model)
```

output is

```
<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential at 0x7f3d554f6710>
```

My question is that is there any way to see a better result of Keras, meaning if i print `model` i can see that i have 3 hidden layers with first hidden layer having 512 hidden units and 784 input units, 2nd hidden layer having 512 input units and 32 hidden units and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

model.summary() will print he entire model for you.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512,activation = 'relu',input_shape=(28*28,)))
model.add(Dense(32,activation ='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               401920    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 32)                16416     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                330       
=================================================================
Total params: 418,666
Trainable params: 418,666
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________
```

Comment: Why is `Output Shape` having 1st parameter None? And does `Param #` shows weights of model?

Comment: Param is the number of weights. For the first layer weights = 28 X 28 X 512 + 512=401920. Last term is the 512 bias weights. None means inputs will be provided as batches.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try `plot_model()`

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation = 'relu',input_shape=(28*28,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation ='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model  
plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

[image]